# Error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified, provider: SQL Network Interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I recently started to work on Visual Studio 19 (I was working with Visual Studio 17)

This error came from nowhere:

> Error Locating Server/Instance Specified, provider: SQL Network Interfaces

I've tried every solution on the internet and the services are running but nothing worked. I'm also working with SSMS 18.

I would be thankful if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: check the connection string wherever you are using

Comment: It sounds like all of your client protocols are disabled. Have you checked that you have the TCP/IP protocol enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Native Client Configuration (32bit and 64bit)?

Comment: @viveknuna the connection string did not changed, it was working, and then it didnt

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I checked it and it's enabled